# Filtering a table

Tags: jquery, filter, html-table

I'm creating a prototype website with a table. I just want to know how can I filter the table contents? Example I have two buttons which are 'writers' and 'illustrators' and when I click the button for writer, I just want the table to just show the writers.

Is it possible to filter it using the table row <strike>id</strike> class?

Like:

```
<table>    
  <tr class="writer">
     <td>John Doe </td>
     <td>Jan 01, 1980</td>
     <td>jondoe@domain.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr clas="illustrator">
     <td>Jane Doe </td>
     <td>Sept 01, 1980</td>
     <td>janedoe@domain.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="illustrator">
     <td>Mel Smith </td>
     <td>Aug 01, 1980</td>
     <td>meeeeel@domain.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="writer">
     <td>Harry Smith </td>
     <td>Dec 01, 1980</td>
    <td>hsmith@domain.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or are there any easy way to do it?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SFBr3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#illustrator').click(function () {
        $('table tr.writer').hide();
        $('table tr.illustrator').show();
    })
    $('#writer').click(function () {
        $('table tr.writer').show();
        $('table tr.illustrator').hide();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SFBr3/)